# Why app crashes if user enter a simple text eg "hi"

Tags: java, android-studio, crash

Source are :
MainActivity.java-

```
package com.amostrone.akash.safebrowser;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.amostrone.akash.safebrowser.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void search(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Browser.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();

        if(message == null || message.trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            message = "http://www.android.com"; // TODO Add your own WEBSITE
        }
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.amostrone.akash.safebrowser.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Search here." />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="search" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Browser.java

```
 package com.amostrone.akash.safebrowser;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Browser extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        if (!((message.substring(0, 11)).equals("http://www.") || (message.substring(0, 12)).equals("https://www.")))
            check();

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(message);
    }

    void check() {
        // WWW
        if(message.substring(0,4).equals("www."))
        {
            message = "http://" + message;
            return;
        }
        // Google Search
        message = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + message + "&rct=j" ;
    }
}
```

Browser.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_browser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.amostrone.akash.safebrowser.Browser">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So my problem is that when i enter any text like "http://www.google.con.in" or just "www.google.co.in", everything works fine but when i enter just simple text like "stackoverflow" app crashes.It crashes even before system call the button "search" function "search(View view)". 
Please help--

Comment: plese help i am not very experianced in android development

Comment: where and how does it crash?

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: No there r none

Comment: @wombat it crashes when the I enter text like "google" which don't have http:// or http://www. Text in its biggning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you are executing a substring on your message String, but it's too short. 
As example:

```
message.substring(0, 11)
```

This will do a substring from index zero to 11, but what happens if the string have only a length of 4? There will be a exception. 
You should extract the checks into an new method and do the length checks on the string before calling the substring method.

```
if(message.length() > 10){
  message.substring(0,11);
}
```

Comment: *lenght()* - never heard of it ;-)

Comment: But still it crashes before system call the search() function of button search

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for this hint :D I've edited it :D